# JQuery sortable, expand to multiple lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm wondering how to expand the answer in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745766/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-jquery-sortable-connected-lists), the answer provided by Guillermo?

Within the function this clause is repeated, once for each list:

```
$("#sortable3").sortable({
  receive: function (event, ui) {
      var pasteItem = checkList("sortable3", $(this).data().uiSortable.currentItem);
      if (!pasteItem){
           $(this).data().uiSortable.currentItem.remove();
      }
  }
```

});

If there were more lists (I'd like to adopt this solution to something I'm working on) this clause looks like it would need to be repeated for each sortable list.

Let's say I have 10 such lists, to me this doesn't seem to be efficient, though Guillermo might have written the code more efficiently if he was to know that there were more than two lists.